# When to write custom ember-data adapter?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm writing an ember application that pulls the majority of it's data from the Lastfm API. The API is not RESTful. I'm not sure what what level of abstraction I should customize. Should I go down the path of writing a custom LastFm ember-data adapter? Or should I just sidestep ember-data all together?

They return data similar to this:

```
{ "recenttracks" : { "meta" : {}, "tracks" : [ { track info }, { track info } ] } }
```

For requesting data, they have a scheme that involves sending a `method` parameter. So, not the worst thing ever, but certainly not RESTful.

Anyway, just looking for a bit of direction as I'm new to ember-data.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I would create a new adapter, not necessarily `RESTAdapter`, passing parameters to `find` and `findAll`:

```
var lastFmAdapter = DS.Adapter.create({
  find: function (store, type, id) { },
  findAll: function (store, type) { }
});
```

Comment: more info please? i would appreciate it

Comment: yea more detail would be great. I want to create an Adapter which downloads and caches results on first access, and can be refreshed as needed. The API isn't necessarily purely "RESTful", so I'd like to walk through the structure myself too.

Comment: have a look at the implementation: https://github.com/emberjs/data/tree/v2.7.0/addon/adapters -> you can basically add your own implementation into app/adapters/application.js